# When using CSS Grid auto-fit can I get the grid cells to expand to fit their content?

Tags: css, css-grid

When doing something like `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));` I would like my content to not spill out of the grid cell if it is too big or long. Here is an example [codepen](https://codepen.io/markhaslam/pen/MWgJJEQ) I created that illustrates the problem. I added some long text with no line breaks to the 3rd grid item. As you can see you the text goes off the edge. I would like the 3rd grid item to expand to fit the text. I am okay if the entire 3rd column has to expand as well, I would just like it to fit the text.

Here is one more slightly modified example [codepen#2](https://codepen.io/markhaslam/pen/zYONNQb) with just 2 grid item and the same problem. When those 2 items are still on the same row I would like it to behave as if I had declared `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;` but then still having the 2nd item wrap to a second row when small enough.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

you just have to do make `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, auto));` max property to `auto`, it will expand according to content.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, auto));
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
}

.item {
  background: #ffc600;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">Three...Long TextSpilling</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
  <div class="item">15</div>
</div>
```

Comment: He doesn't need to break word, that's was my first answer before editing it, he wants to extend div size to fit the connected words. Or whatever the child size parent should fit not overflow the text.

Comment: The word wrote there is without space thats why i sued that, otherwise he has to remove `grid` property from item it will work.

Comment: Please find his commitment on my answer.

Comment: I have made changes accordingly. so you can check now i am not using  `break-word`

Comment: I also submitted answer like yours, i thought he want to fit text inside parent, but he commented on my answer, he wants to fit parent not the text, that's why i changed my answer to fit parent, and it works good but without using display grid.

Comment: You just added space between, dear please check his comment on my answer, and check my answer that's what he wants, he wants min size for div to be 100 px and divs can fit to contain the child size, eg. child has image width 200 px so parent width should be 200 px and all other divs still 100 px

Comment: Yes, I do not want the word to break, you added a space in my word. Even if I remove the the space you added the column still shrinks smaller than the content. I want it to always fit the content.

Comment: @Torvaldy try it with `flex`, it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

please check the below css code :

```
.container {
  display: block;
}

.item {
  background: #ffc600;
  display: grid;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  justify-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I intentionally didn't put any breaks in the word. I would like other types of content to be fitted as well, such as an image. I want the column to be able to grow to the size of the for content. I want it to behave as if the columns were defined with fr units.

Comment: Thanks, this does function like I want it too, but do you know if there is a way to achieve this same functionality with using CSS Grid? I'm thinking it just may not be possible with using Grid.

Comment: actually i have tried a lot to achieve this by css grid, it's not working, but I don't know if we can do this or not, my answer is alternative way to do your task.